# Ubuntu server cannot detect my WiFi (Intel 8265) card

Tags: server, wireless, system-installation, 18.04, iwlwifi

My Ubuntu server cannot detect my WiFi (Intel 8265) card.

Because the installer can't detect my WiFi card, it won't proceed.

I don't have the same issue when installing Ubuntu desktop.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; locate iwlwifi.ko`

Comment: I don't think I can get a terminal when installing Ubuntu server?

Comment: The problem may be that server edition doesn't have the wifi kernel modules